# Linux, secondary display is goes black

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, external-display, twinview

I'm using Archlinux with Gnome 3.2 and the "nvidia" drivers. I'm using a 15" Apple MacBook Pro with an Apple Cinema Display attached as my secondary display. After about three minutes, the external display is covered in black (the backlight stays on); only the first line of pixels remains, when I move the mouse way up I can see the tip of the mouse cursor through this 1 line of pixels. The display in the laptop continues to run without issue. Keypresses and mouse movements targeted at the external display work, I just can't see them. Switching back to the primary display with Disper and then back to the external fixes the problem but only for another three minutes.

I've tried changing settings with "xset", killing the screensaver, turning off DPMS, etc. but nothing seems to work. It is driving me totally crazy, for now I can't really use my external display. This is a new problem that cropped up after some un-interesting looking updates yesterday.

Has anyone seen anything similar, or have a suggestion that might fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tracked down the source of this issue. Instead, I rolled back to the previous version of the X server and all of the associated libraries. So it goes.